# looping a html table with inputs to get values

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table that looks like this

```
<table id="tableScanItems" class="table">
        <th>Scan Item</th>
        <th>Inactive</th>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input1' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input2' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input3' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox3' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On a button click I have this jQuery that runs.

```
$("#tableScanItems tr").each(function (){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
        ...get the values for each row and do stuff
    });
});
```

I need to loop the html table to get the values of the input type=text and the input type=checkbox

The JS does loop properly and gets the input type=text values but not the input type=checkbox values. Do I need to specify a different parameter in the .each to see the value of checkbox?

Ryan

**EDIT**
If I do this I cannot see the values of the user inputs.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
    alert(this.value)
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - this fiddle prints out IDs of all 6 inputs. https://jsfiddle.net/acwp51qt/

Comment: Thanks @PetrHejda I appreciate your time. I am trying to get the values of the of the inputs.

Comment: In that case, you can use the jQuery `val()` method - https://api.jquery.com/val/ ... So instead of calling `$(this).attr('id')` you'd be calling `$(this).val()`

Comment: @PetrHejda, `this.value` works like that since `this` refers to the Element itself, in an `.each` function loop. `.closest('tr')` is pointless though. Your issue is that there is no Event that fires this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop like below.  You need to treat checkboxes differently to get their values:

```
$("#tableScanItems tr").each(function (){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (elem.is(':checkbox')) {
           console.log( !!elem.attr("checked"));
        } else {
            console.log(elem.val());
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5yt9hon1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check some checkboxes and hit submit.  You will see the values of the checkboxes in a div.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {               
                 var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked') 
                 if (result.length > 0) {
                     var resultString = result.length + " checked <br/><br/>"
                     result.each(function () {
                         resultString+= $(this).val() + "<br/>";
                     });
                     $('#divCheckboxValues').html(resultString);
                 }
                 else {
                     $('#divCheckboxValues').html(" No checkbox checked");
                 }
             });
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableScanItems" class="table">
        <th>Scan Item</th>
        <th>Inactive</th>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input1' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input2' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input3' class='form-control'/></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox3' class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<br />
<div id="divCheckboxValues">
</div>
```